# tee, sed - how to strip out block of text denoted by a start and stop symbol

Tags: bash, sed, gnu, tee

When I do a build, I often use `make --print-data-base` to debug my files. However, I don't always want to see the entire database.

The start of the database is denoted by `# Make data base, printed on` and the stop by `# Finished Make data base`.

I know I could make a script that would do this after the build is done - maybe I should just do that - but is there a way to do it with `sed`?

`make all --print-data-base 2>&1 | tee build-with-data-base.err | sed **something** | tee build-with-no-data-base.err`

The issue I see here is that there is state involved: when you hit the start of the database portion, you turn the stream off and when you hit the end, you turn the stream back on.

Is it possible to do this with `sed` or should I just do it with a script?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another make command or option that would print files for debug but not the data base? Given the current flag name it seems just weird.

Comment: @Aaron I'd have to run `make` again without `--print-data-base`

Comment: I don't get it... but I guess my answer will work anyway.

Comment: @Aaron the database is the debug output

Comment: yes, and you don't want that output, and you could avoid that output by not using the `--print-data-base` ; so why not just do that? You say "because I would have to run `make` again", but you also have to do that if you at first didn't include the `sed` command and now want the output database-free :-/

Comment: @Aaron because if the build fails, then I do want to have it and I'd rather not need to run the build again. The build is the time consuming part.

Comment: Alright, understood. I feel like producing both the "standard" and "debug" outputs is wasteful though. IMO you should carry on using `--print-data-base` since you sometimes need the debug output, but only produce the "no-debug" output when the make has succeeded. Anyway my answer should work well to transform the debug output into a no-debug output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed you can use ranges whose start and end are described by a `/test/` :

```
echo "a
b
c
d
e
f" | sed  '/b/,/e/d'   # delete the lines from b to e
a
f
```

In your case you could possibly use the following `sed` command :

```
sed '/# Make data base, printed on/,/# Finished Make data base/d'
```